# If husband and wife are both working, does wife have to contribute money to running the household?

Tags: fiqh, husband-wife, family, finance

Is it always man's responsibility to run the house? Does wife *has to* contribute in case where she has a job? What is the situation where husband is jobless and wife is working? What is Islamic ruling about this.

Comment: Posting this as a comment for now until I or someone else provide real evidence, but just to sum up, the answers to your questions are:  Yes, No, No.

Comment: Well in my country I must say it's quite the contrary. The man is responsible for matters outside home and the woman is coordinator and manager of the inside work.

Comment: @HamedMomeni actually the question is about monetary contribution based on income, but good point.

Comment: @oshirowanen, that's also true according to Shia perspective AFAIK.

Comment: @HamedMomeni, women managing the inside works in Iran is more cultural than Islamic, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

The wife CANNOT BE FORCED to pay a penny. It's totally a man's duty. If he has a shortage, then he is forced to decrease THEIR standard of living, this does not give him the right to ask his wife to share the pay.

The wife can, of course, help her husband any time favourably.

Many evidences are included in [this](http://www.islam-qa.com/ar/ref/3054) arabic fatwa.

Comment: Can the wife be ASKED to contribute and not force? Is that OK?

Comment: @TheTruthSeaker I revised some Fatwas searching about this question. I did not find (till now) a specific evidence. But it seems OK. All fatwas I read concentrate on: Wives may spend money "favorably".

Comment: CANNOT BE FORCED is not the correct way of answering. If he can ask for it, the makes some a case that she should be helping in rent. I am looking for a rule, should she be paying or should she not be paying. Thanks

Comment: The rule: She is not responsible for paying. If she wishes to help, it's not forbidden. What is forbidden is forcing her to pay.

Comment: Ok I was able to read the fitwa in [english](http://www.islam-qa.com/en/ref/3054). It merely says that Man is responsible for their wives food, clothes, shelter and other necessities which is understood because man is the source of income. But what if the wife is earning also. It does not address that part, which is my question.

Answer (score 0):

No.According to the following, even if the wife has a job she has no responsibility to contribute to expenses.

> الرِّجالُ قَوَّامُونَ عَلَى النِّساءِ بِما فَضَّلَ اللَّهُ بَعْضَهُمْ عَلى‏ بَعْضٍ وَ بِما أَنْفَقُوا مِنْ أَمْوالِهِمْ

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  We suggest you expand a little bit more in your answer, as it is now it is quite short.  Thank you.